# Wordpress removing the list container <ul> from the custom menu output

Tags: wordpress, menu

any suggestions on how to get rid of ***ul*** tag wrapped around ***li*** tags in custom menu here at

http://www.blueoceanportfolios.com/careers/

the custom menu is outputted with nested  tags around like

```
<ul id="menu-home" class="navLeft"><li><a href="http://www.blueoceanportfolios.com/careers/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.blueoceanportfolios.com/careers/?page_id=18">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to take out the  tags and already passed the container => false parameter before outputting custom menu as mentioned at wordpress codex, below is code again.

```
 $args = array(
  //  'menu' => 'primary',
   // 'sort_column' => '',
    'container' => 'false',
    //'container_id'=>'myID',
    'menu_class' => 'navLeft',
    'walker' => new my_walker()
);


wp_nav_menu( $args );
```

Comment: Strange idea, why do you want to remove `ul` ? `li` element must to be inside `ul` or `ol`...

Answer (score 1):

Try `'container' => false,` without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Is just easier than that.
just use the parameter item_wrap from the wp_nav_menu function

```
<?php

$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```

change it to 'items_wrap' => '%3$s'

that's all :)